# How do I make slideToggle() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup

I have been trying to make a tiny color picker other than just `<input type="color">`, and I wanted to make the popup with jQuery. I tried to code it myself, but it didn't work. Am I missing something?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#picker').click(function(){
    $('#pickerWindow').toggleSlide();
  });
});
```

CSS

```
#pickerWindow {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Also, I am open to any other types of color picker suggestions.

Comment: error in browser console would tell you that `toggleSlide` isn't a function....which might make you want to look in the api docs and realize it is spelled differently

Comment: i guess i have to look at the console more! thank you very much!

Comment: absolutely...is first thing to do when code not working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sould use [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)... Not `toggleSlide()` which doesn't exist.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#picker').click(function(){
    $('#pickerWindow').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#pickerWindow {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pickerWindow"></div>
<button id="picker">Picker</button>
```